# how to call WCF Service in post man post request

Tags: wcf, postman, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

how to call WCF Service in PostMan  or any other WebService Software Please help me this
c# code

> URL POST: http://localhost:20826/Service1.svc?wsdl

```
 public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService , IService1
   {

            [WebMethod]
           public GetResponse RequestApiToken(string CallerId)
          {
          GetResponse response = new GetResponse();
          string CallerIdget = CallerId
          return response;
          }
    }
```

Request Body

```
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <RequestApiToken xmlns="http://localhost:20826/">
          <CallerId>sadassdasdasdsadsd</CallerId>
        </RequestApiToken>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```